# Defining recursive models in Pydantic?

Tags: python, oop, types, jsonschema, pydantic

How can I define a recursive Pydantic model?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Task(BaseModel):
    name: str
    subtasks: List[Task] = []
```

but when I run that I get the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c6dca1d390fe> in <module>
      2 from pydantic import BaseModel
      3
----> 4 class Task(BaseModel):
      5     name: str
      6     subtasks: List[Task] = []

<ipython-input-1-c6dca1d390fe> in Task()
      4 class Task(BaseModel):
      5     name: str
----> 6     subtasks: List[Task] = []
      7

NameError: name 'Task' is not defined
```

I looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything. For example, at the page on ["Recursive Models"](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#recursive-models), but it seems to be about nesting subtypes of `BaseModel` not about a recursive type definition.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Alex Hall's answer is correct — you need `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your code. This blog post goes into a little more detail about what's going on there: https://dev.to/tiangolo/the-future-of-fastapi-and-pydantic-is-bright-3pbm

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either put `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the file, or change your annotation to `List['Task']`.

The relevant pydantic documentation is here: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/postponed_annotations/

But the error in your question is not pydantic specific, that's just how type annotations work.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on the accepted answer from Alex Hall:

From the Pydantic docs, it appears the call to `update_forward_refs()` is still required whether or not `annotations` is imported.

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Task(BaseModel):
    name: str
    subtasks: List['Task'] = []


Task.update_forward_refs()
```

or

```py
# python3.7+
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Task(BaseModel):
    name: str
    subtasks: List[Task] = []


Task.update_forward_refs()
```

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/postponed_annotations/#self-referencing-models

Comment: If you are using pydantic V2 onwards `update_forward_refs` is deprecated and you'd want to use `model_rebuild` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a situation in which I want to run a root validator on the class.
What happens is that, although the above solution seem to work find in some cases, the value of the recursive field `subtasks` doesn't show up in the `values` dictionary parameter of the `@root_validator`.

I ended up with declaring

```
subtasks: List[Dict]
```

and recursively build the subtasks objects in the `@root_validator`:

```
subtasks = values.get('subtasks')
if subtasks:
    values['subtasks']=[Task(**subtask) for subtask in subtasks]
```